# How To Get an Occupancy Map of a .ply File?

Tags: python, c++, 3d, mapping, point-cloud-library

I need to create a map of a camera's view. In this view, there will be a bunch of people and behind of these people should be a blind spot for us. So, what I need is basically creating an occupancy map of 3D point cloud data (using .ply or .pcd file) and consider those blind spot as occupied since the camera cannot see behind the people. Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Your request is too broad and needs to be more specific. Tell us what you tried and where it failed.

Comment: Note: Unless you are comparing two languages or seeking assistance porting from one language to another, you probably do not want 2 language tags. Pick the one language that you are more likely to use.

Comment: I have seen some examples of grip mapping. But those did not consider behind the objects and showed them as an empty grip in the map. I need something that fills behind an object. I couldn't find such algorithm. Maybe I've missed it. I'm wondering if anyone knows how to create this kind of map.

Comment: @user4581301 In this area, I've seen implementations in both languages. I know these languages. So, it shouldn't be a problem for me understanding codes in these languages. Maybe there is another implementation in another language, I'm open for these kind of suggestions as well.